# SwiftUI and iOS app backward compatibility

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have an app that I developed several years ago in Objective C, but I'm currently re-writing it in SwiftUI. The old version runs on iOS 9.0 and up, but the new version will only work on the latest versions of iOS (14.0 and up).

Is there a way to ensure that users with older iPhones can continue running the old version, while users with newer iPhones can use the new SwiftUI version?

Comment: The update simply won't appear for users with older iOS versions.  In App Store Connect you can select versions that will remain available for people who have previously purchased your app and are running older iOS versions (in the case where they have deleted the app or erased their phone).  People who have older iOS and have never purchased your app won't be able to do so.

Comment: you can build just 1 app that controls device iOS version, then decide which code or version should be run. easy

Comment: This is something I am considering doing and in my investigations thus far, I have found that this is possible, however, it will require some thought into architecture of your new & old code. You will probably have to build and maintain two versions of a view, one for anything below iOS 13 and the SwiftUI versions for 13+. This would mean adding @available wrappers to identify the appropriate view you will need in the logic that displays screens in your app. Consideration must be made in reusing business logic code for both. Still investigating, so, this is my understanding as it stands.